# Why $0 \le r < s (r, s \in Z)$ leads to $2^{r+1} -1 < 2^s$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$r < s \Leftrightarrow 2^r < 2^s \Leftrightarrow 2^{r+1} < 2^{s+1}$

But what does the above have to do with $2^{r+1} -1 < 2^s$?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $r,s\in\mathbb Z$ we have:$$s>r\implies s\geq{r+1}\implies2^s\geq2^{r+1}>2^{r+1}-1$$

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, if $0 \le r < s (r, s \in Z)$,
$$2^{r+1} -1 < 2^{r+1}$$

Here, $s\ge r+1$

As $2^x$ increases for increasing $x$,
$$2^{r+1}\le2^s$$
or
$$2^{r+1} -1 < 2^s$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $r,s \in \mathbb Z$, $r < s$ is the same as saying $r +1 \leq s$. Hence,

$$2^{r+1} \leq 2^s < 2^s + 1$$
and it follows that
$$2^{r+1} -1 < 2^s$$